# How to extract a sublist by the value of the first element from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to extract a sublist from a nested list based on the first element in each list. I have the following nested list:

```python
input = [
    ['nom', 'N', 'eye'],
    ['acc', 'E', 'computer'],
    ['dat', 'C', 'screen']
    ]
```

I want to have a function which returns `['nom', 'N', 'eye']` when the first element of the sublist `'nom'` is inputted, for instance:

```python
output = ['nom', 'N', 'eye'] # When the function takes 'nom' as its argument
output = ['acc', 'E', 'computer'] # When the function takes 'acc' as its argument
output = ['dat', 'C', 'screen'] # When the function takes 'dat' as its argument
```

How should I achieve this with python3.6+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
my_list = [
    ['nom', 'N', 'eye'],
    ['acc', 'E', 'computer'],
    ['dat', 'C', 'screen']
]
my_input = input("Enter first string to find: ")

for lis in my_list:
    if lis[0] == my_input:
        print(lis)
        break
```

Output:

```
Enter variable name: nom
['nom', 'N', 'eye']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the argument is in the first index of input then the code is:

```
output = []
def extract_sublist(keyword: str):
    for li in input_list:
        if keyword == li[0]:
            output.append(li[0:])
```